# Adding Semantic Highlighting to an Eclipse editor plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, editor

In eclipse, the Java editor highlights the declaration of function and class names. As far as I can tell from my googling, this dynamic highlighting is done using semantic highlighting, however I have yet to find any tutorials on how to actually write the code to do so. Does anyone know how it works or how to write a simple one. I've looked through the Eclipse documentation and didn't find anything, and the JDT source didn't help either.